# Get .so filename by command

Tags: debian

Python 3 is installed in my Debian system. I know the .so name is libpython3.7.so and the directory is /usr/lib/python3.7/config-3.7m-x86_64-linux-gnu/

How do I get the name of the Python library using a command from a terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can list python related installed libraries with:

```
dpkg-query -l 'libpython*'
```

Then with the package name you can list files in a package with:

```
dpkg -L <package_name>
```